# XPath expression to select nodes between a defined sequence of preceding and succeeding nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I've got the following structured XML file:

```
   <w:document>
      <w:body>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:t/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:t/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:instrText/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:t/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:instrText/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
           <w:r>
              <w:t/>
           </w:r>
        </w:p>
     </w:body>
  </w:document>
```

and I'm trying desperately to find an **XPath** expression to select all `<w:t>` nodes that are between two `<w:instrText>` nodes. `<w:t>` nodes basically appear freely all around the XML document, but I'm only interested in those between two `<w:instrText>` nodes.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: You sample document is not valid. There are no closing tags for the `t` and `x` elements. Or should all these be self-contained tags like so: `<t />`? Please correct so that we can give meaningful answers.

Comment: Okay excuse me, let me edit my question and provide the real structure.

Comment: As this is OpenXml, shouldn't you rather be looking at the `<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />`,  `<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />` and `<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />` elements? I assume you want to extract the field text? This is rather complex to do in XPath, because fields may not only be split up over several runs/paragraphs/etc, but may also be nested (The canonical example would be hyperlink fields inside a TOC field).

Comment: @0xA3 You are right, this is Open XML and I'm trying to extract the text that is between two custom defined fields. Since my question here is basically about XPath because that was the best approach I first came up with, I'll rate the best answer about it, but you've solved my real problem. So thank you ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying desperately to find an
>   XPath expression to select all `<w:t>`
>   nodes that are between two
>   `<w:instrText>` nodes

```
/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:instrText/following::w:t
      [count(.|/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:instrText/preceding::w:t) =
       count(/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r/w:instrText/preceding::w:t)]
```

Node set intersection expression

Comment: @Alejandro:  Could  you link to an explanation of the node set intersection test?  I always get confused by the count(.) style testing.

Comment: @geoffc: unfortunately I can't find a preview for Dr. Micheal Kay book. This is know as Kaysan node set intersection expression, because he was the first to point out. How does it work? Mainly because `|` union operator results in a non duplicate node set. So, performing the union between a node with a node set that already contains this node, doesn't change the count (meaning it's included in set theory)

Answer (score 1):

Is it not as simple as: `//x/t` ?